# Non-static method Redis::get() cannot be called statically in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, redis, laravel-5.4

i am working on Redis to store data Everything is working fine in my local system. i have successfully installed redis also in laravel  with this command **composer require predis/predis** also and Redis setup of window also installed. Now when i store data in Redis like this:-

```
Redis::set('first',"My first Test"); // put data in Redis key
echo Redis ::get('first'); // get data
```

Above code is working fine in my local system. when i try to use this code in live server it is showing the below error:-
[image]
Please help me to resolve this issue. We are using amazon-ec2 server Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Had you also tried this command in server?: `composer require predis/predis`

Comment: i have uploaded vendor folder and composer.json

Comment: I think we never upload vendor folder in server, just update composer and that install all packages using `composer update`!

Comment: but every time when i iintsalled package in my local system like maatwebsite excel,.. etc i have uploaded vendor folder and composer .json then that was running fine

Comment: Yeah its fine, but actual thing is we never uploads the vendor folder in server/git. We always ignore in `.gitignore` file. Just update composer.json file and composer update in server. So, that installed all package files in their vendor folder! And not missing any files!

Comment: remove the vendor folder and install again

Comment: should i run composer update on server or should i firstly delete the folder ?

Comment: First delete folder and take as a backup for you, then run `composer update` command in server. So, that it installed all the packages defined in composer file. Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: ok i will try ... should i rename vendor folder in server??

Comment: Yes, you can renamed it as a backup also, and when you run command then it creates vendor folder.! That's fine. Let me know when it works :)

Comment: ok.. thanks will try and let you knw if it works

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: delete : use Redis;
try
add : use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

Comment: i am already using this use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

Comment: r u make changes in config folders?

Comment: No.. i have no do any changes

Comment: try once by change 'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),in queue.php and  'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'redis') in session.php

Comment: @HirenGohel it's not working still :(

Comment: @RamAnji Still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154411/discussion-between-ramanji-and-kunal).

Comment: Have you update server's `.env` file as same as local?

Comment: yes i have put server configuation host and port all things i have done

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue. But I believe its related to php 7 rather than Larevel 5.4 because I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I still have the problem.

I came across 2 solutions

1. Use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;` instead of `use Redis;` if you want to call the Redis methods statically.
2. Change to dynamic calling

`$redis = new Redis();
 $redis->set('boo','Have beer and relax!')
 $redis->get('boo');`

Comment: ya i have tried this also its working now tell how can i get redis "boo" in another function

Comment: thanks. worked with use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis; instead of use Redis; if you want to call the Redis methods statically.

Answer (score 3):

- Just remove or comment out extension=php_redis.dll from your php.ini
- Laravel and server Redis conflicts with name "Redis"
- This will work

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel database config you can define a client for your Redis handler.
As you have installed predis, your Redis database configuration should look like this

```
'redis' => [

           'client' => 'predis',

           'cluster' => false,

           'default' => [
                  'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                  'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                  'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                  'database' => 0,
           ],
```

PhpRedis extension and Laravel alias for Redis Facades are same which is creating the issue. In case you want to use the PhpRedis extension you need to change the alias keyword defined in app.php and client in the database config.